# Filter a Data.frame based on Rownames

Tags: r, r-rownames

```
c <- data.frame("c1"=c(78,89,0),"c2"=c(89,89,34),"c3"=c(56,0,4))
row.names(c) <- c("zebra","fish","zucchini")


c <- rm(grep("z",rownames(c))) ??
```

hopefully short question, short answer: What is wrong with the above code? It says me "must contain names or character strings". How do I remove all rows that contain z in their rownames. In this reprex only fish is left.

Thank you sooo much

Comment: Hi, may i suggest that you create an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Also, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: also consider not using `c` as a data.frame name because that is a function name in r

Answer (score 3):

**1) grepl** There are several problems:

- the test data in the question has errors so we use the one in the Note at the end
- although not strictly wrong, `c` is not a good name to use given the ubiquitous use of the `c` function in R so we use `cc` instead
- we use `grepl` with an `l` on the end instead of `grep` in order to get a logical vector result and then use ! to negate it.
- `rm` is used to remove objects from the workspace, not to remove rows from a data frame, so we use subscripts instead.

No packages are used.

```
cc[!grepl("z", rownames(cc)), ]
##      c1 c2 c3
## fish 89 89  0
```

**2) grep** As an alternative it would also be possible to use `grep` with the `invert=TRUE` argument:

```
cc[grep("z", rownames(cc), invert = TRUE), ]
##      c1 c2 c3
## fish 89 89  0
```

**3) substr** In the example the `z` character always appears as the first character so if this is the case in general we could alternately use:

```
cc[substr(rownames(cc), 1, 1) != "z", ]
##      c1 c2 c3
## fish 89 89  0
```

**3a) startsWith**  Another approach if `z` must be the first character is:

```
cc[!startsWith(rownames(cc), "z"), ]
##      c1 c2 c3
## fish 89 89  0
```

### Note

```
cc <- data.frame(c1 = c(78, 89, 0), c2 = c(89, 89, 34), c3 = c(56, 0, 4))
row.names(cc) <- c("zebra", "fish", "zucchini")
```

Answer (score 1):

Rm removes objects.  You are trying to filter on row.

```
c <- data.frame("c1"=c(78,89,0),"c2"=c(89,89,34),"c3"=c(56,0,4))
row.names(c) <- c("zebra","fish","zucchini")

print( c )
c[ !grepl("z",rownames(c)) , ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example uses deprecated properties. I have edited it somewhat.

/Edit: Now I'm understanding that you wish to remove those rows, see the following example:

```
c <- tibble("c1"=c(78,89,0),"c2"=c(89,89,34),"c3"=c(56,0,4),
            "rownames"=c("zebra","fish","zucchini")) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("rownames")

c[!grepl("i", rownames(c)),] 

      c1 c2 c3
zebra 78 89 56
```

Also, as pointed out before, c should not be an object name, as it also is a central function in R.